# Tomcat with minimal jars

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, tomcat8

For a usual legacy Java app (Spring, JSP+JSTL) I want to remove unused libraries from Tomcat's classpath i.e. from lib folder. Now I see 25 jars there. I don't need clustering and websockets and other stuff so I decided to remove some of them. Which one I can safely remove and which one are required?

I found a description of each library on [Class loader howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) page and in **bold** I marked my suggestions:

- annotations-api.jar — JavaEE annotations classes. **Required**
- catalina.jar — Implementation of the Catalina servlet container portion of Tomcat. **Required**
- catalina-ant.jar — Tomcat Catalina Ant tasks. **Looks like it is not used by tomcat itself**
- catalina-ha.jar — High availability package. **Optional for clustering**
- catalina-storeconfig.jar — Generation of XML configuration files from current state **Optional for clustering**
- catalina-tribes.jar — Group communication package. **Optional for clustering**
- ecj-*.jar — Eclipse JDT Java compiler. **Required for JSPs, but maybe you can precompile them somehow and remove the compiler**
- el-api.jar — EL 3.0 API. **Required for expressions inside JSP**
- jasper.jar — Tomcat Jasper JSP Compiler and Runtime. **Required for JSP**
- jasper-el.jar — Tomcat Jasper EL implementation. **Required for JSP**
- jsp-api.jar — JSP 2.3 API. **Required for JSP**
- servlet-api.jar — Servlet 3.1 API. **Definitely Required**
- tomcat-api.jar — Several interfaces defined by Tomcat. **Looks Required**
- tomcat-coyote.jar — Tomcat connectors and utility classes. **Required**
- tomcat-dbcp.jar — Database connection pool implementation based on package-renamed copy of Apache Commons Pool and Apache Commons DBCP. **Optional and it's better to replace with HakiriCP**
- tomcat-i18n-**.jar — Optional JARs containing resource bundles for other languages. **As default bundles are also included in each individual JAR, they can be safely removed if no internationalization of messages is needed.**
- tomcat-jdbc.jar — An alternative database connection pool implementation, known as Tomcat JDBC pool. See documentation for more details. **Optional and it's better to replace with HakiriCP**
- tomcat-util.jar — Common classes used by various components of Apache Tomcat. **Looks Required**
- tomcat-websocket.jar — WebSocket 1.1 implementation **Optional for WebSockets**
- websocket-api.jar — WebSocket 1.1 API **Optional for WebSockets**

So I removed:

- catalina-ant.jar - I don't use Ant and actually I have no idea why this jar is distributed with Tomcat
- tomcat-websocket.jar and websocket-api.jar  - I don't use WebSockets
- tomcat-dbcp.jar and tomcat-jdbc.jar - I use HikariCP form app lib.
- JAR's for clustering: catalina-ha.jar, catalina-tribes.jar **catalina-storeconfig.jar** (but I'm not sure that this related to Clustering only)
- tomcat-i18n-* - some jars for localization but I don't know what I lost

Did I removed these jars correctly? If you have any experience on minimizing Tomcat configuration please share with us.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nobody can answer this without knowing about your app thoroughly. If even you can't be sure, how could we? The only way to be certain is thoroughly test your app. And...the entire tomcat lib directory add up to like 15MB, so what's the point of this exercise anyway?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Classes are generally not loaded until needed, so you're probably not lowering the memory footprint by doing this.

Comment: I wont to do that in several reasons:
1. I want fully understand what happening. It turned out that one part of app used old dbcp connection pool while I thought it used Hikari and I need a protection from this.
2. My legacy app already have a big jar hell and I reviewed almost all dependencies. I added JHades to track classpath conflicts. In the same time I trying to split the app to microservices.
3. I want to dokerize the app and to make the image reasonably small.
4. I hope this can increase a little bit upstart: even if class is unused  each JAR is scanned on start.

Comment: You said you don't need clustering, you can safely remove clustering related jars.